# How to calculate overlap between different categories in R

Tags: r, dataframe, overlap

I have read around the forum but I have not found my desired answer.

I have the following dataset:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0rIy.png)

The important columns are TGEClass and peptide:

I would like to calculate the overlap between the different TGEclasses

I used calculate.overlap(TGE) from VennDiagram but that does not give me the desired result;

The R code with a dummy dataset:

```
# A simple single-set diagram
C1 <- as.data.frame(letters[1:10])
C2 <- as.data.frame(letters[1:10])
data =cbind(C1,C2)

overlap <- calculate.overlap(data)
overlap = as.data.frame(overlap)
```

The R result:
The result:

```
  a1 a2 a3
1  a  a  a
2  b  b  b
3  c  c  c
4  d  d  d
5  e  e  e
6  f  f  f
```

The desired result will look like this:

TGEClass

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR843.png)

10 genes are expressed in both TGE classes

50 genes in only alternative

60 genes in only short

It is basically a ven diagram but in a table format.

Please note that each gene have a different number of TGE class categories.

I am very new to R so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much,

Ishack

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste them into R. Show the code you actually tried.

Comment: Hi MrFlick I have added the code I tested and the produced result. The problem is my categories are in rows rather than columns. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `VennDiagram::calculate.overlap()` is not very convenient for later use (here using as.data.frame you just got lucky as both vectors are of same size).

You can actually use `tidyverse` to compute it yourself, and return the summary:

```r
library(tidyverse)
list(
  "Cardiome" = letters[1:10],
  "SuperSet" = letters[8:24]
) %>% 
  map2_dfr(., names(.), ~tibble::enframe(.x) %>% mutate(group=.y)) %>% 
  add_count(value) %>%  
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(group2 = ifelse(n()==2, "both", group)) %>% 
  count(group2)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   group2       n
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 both         3
#> 2 Cardiome     7
#> 3 SuperSet    14
```

If you want to stick with the output of `VennDiagram::calculate.overlap()`, you can use something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
overlap <- VennDiagram::calculate.overlap(
  x = list(
    "Cardiome" = letters[1:10],
    "SuperSet" = letters[8:24]
  )
);
map2_dfr(overlap, names(overlap), ~tibble::enframe(.x) %>% mutate(group=.y)) %>% 
  spread(group, group) %>% 
  mutate(a1_only = !is.na(a1) & is.na(a2),
         a2_only = !is.na(a2) & is.na(a1),
         both = !is.na(a2) & !is.na(a1)) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("a1_only", "a2_only", "both"), sum) %>% 
  gather(group, number, everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   group   number
#>   <chr>    <int>
#> 1 a1_only     10
#> 2 a2_only     17
#> 3 both         0
```

Comment: Hi Thanks very much for your answer but how do I export the tibble in the first code as csv please? Sorry for the late reply